# New student thats hit a wall (homework) calc_num_stoplights?

Tags: python

I have been taking an Introduction to Programming course and have caught most of the early stuff.  However, since we have moved on to functions, defined functions I'm a bit overwhelmed, mainly my confidence just got shot.  We have a question currently that says the following;

**Part 1 - Stoplights**

Rosie's Road Co. would like a function to calculate how many stoplights to order for each project. The function must be called calc_num_stoplights and must take these arguments in order:

- Length of road project in miles.
- Number of lanes.

Your function must return an integer representing the number of stoplights to order for the project. The function should count 2 stoplights for each crossing, then add one stoplight for each lane of road. For example, one intersection of 4 lanes would need 6 stoplights (2 for the crossing, 1 for each of 4 lanes).

**The best I have tried so far is the following;**

```
def stoplights_total(lanes):
    stoplights = lanes

def crossing_lights_total(miles):
    crossing_lights = miles * 2

def calc_num_stoplights(miles, lanes):
    road_project_length_miles = (miles)
    number_of_lanes = (lanes)
    total_lights = (int(stoplights_total + crossing_lights_total)*road_project_length)

calc_num_stoplights(miles, lanes)
```

**And this is my error return;**

> ccc_5ed52e8979_7381@runweb15:~$ cd;VOC_SELECTED_FILE="rosies_road_co.py" /bin/bash -c ../resource/scripts/run.sh
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/ccc_v1_s_CJ0y_141397/asn34792_57/asn34793_1/asnlib.0/public/RUN.py", line 15, in 
>           exec(source)
>         File "", line 23, in 
>       NameError: name 'miles' is not defined

Please walk me through this, as I'm not looking for an answer but more of how to go about getting the answer.  The two functions test are 5 miles with 2 lanes (should equal 20) and 2.5 miles with 4 lanes (should equal 12).  Thanks!

Comment: You need to set up the `miles` and `lanes` variables. You can just do `calc_num_stoplights(5,2)` for testing purposes, or read them in from the user, or use command line variables. The last two have plenty of examples on here. BTW, your next problem will be that `stoplights_total + crossing_lights_total` is not the correct way to call functions.

Comment: You need to replace `miles, lanes` in your call to `calc_num_stoplights()` with actual numbers, like `calc_num_stoplights(5, 2)`.

Comment: Finally, although the spec doesn't say, I presume there is one intersection per mile, but then each intersection has lane lights, whereas your code only counts one set of lane lights for the whole distance.

Comment: Why does this have the [tag:bash] tag?

Comment: @Ken Would it be that I need to return both of them in their respective def lines?    Such as return stoplights and return crossing_lights or did I miss that one completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling a function you ask for the function to give you something in return. Therefore you need to add return statements to your functions. You do not have to have a lot of functions for solving this problem as all the math can be solved in just one simple function, see the example below:

```
def calc_num_stoplights(miles, lanes):

    crossing_lights_total = 2 * miles
    stoplights_total = lanes
    road_project_lenght = miles

    numbOfStoplights = int((stoplights_total + crossing_lights_total) * road_project_lenght)

    return numbOfStoplights

numbOfStoplights = calc_num_stoplights(5, 2)

print numbOfStoplights
```

By returning "numbOfStoplights" in the function you can save the returned value in a new variable outside the function as you can see right below the return statement. By doing so the value that the function spits out is saved in the "numbOfStoplights" variable. You can then print the value by printing the "numbOfStoplights"

PS. Im not sure the math is correct but hopefully you can figure that out by your own :)

Comment: So basically any value that we would need later on within the def needs to be returned?  Or is the final value of the def the only thing that can be saved under the returned value?  As in, is there a limit to this?  This helps out a lot by the way.

Comment: You can only do one return from a single function. If you would like to return multiple values you could save all the values you would like to return in a list and then return the list. If you are pleased with the answer please consider checking the green checkmark :)